# translate function in xslt 1.0 giving error

Tags: xml, debugging, xpath, syntax-error, xslt-1.0

I am trying to change some attribute value at a given xpath location, using the translate function but getting the following error:
**Unexpected token "," in path expression wrt /abc/,/abc**
My code is :

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(/abc/,/abc/xyz,$var)"/>
```

Is their a fix?

Comment: As the error message clearly states, the error is caused by the invalid path `/abc/,/abc/xyz,$var` and has nothing to do with the translate() function. Please post a [mcve] and explain what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Before using any XPath function, check the spec. I think you're imagining what it might do based on the name of the function. And XPath doesn't let you write regular expressions using Javascript syntax.